# My browser have been hacked.. or?

Tags: wordpress, forms, google-chrome, contacts

I just looked over my blog today and discovered a problem with my comment form. I've already installed and activated the Akismet anti-spam plugin so I don't actually receive the spam comments, but my comment form has been pre-filled with the following:

name: "Buy free viagra"
email: "buyyouviagra@here.com"
website: "http://www.freeviagra.com"

I have absolutely no idea as to how it happened. I haven't noticed any other strange use of the site. I only have two other pluins installed, which is published directly from Wordpress.org and I have checked the theme for modifications, but found nothing.

Now this is where it gets really odd. I tried checking my blog using Internet Explorer and Firefox but nothing wrong with those - it only happens when I look at it using Google Chrome. Now has my browser been hacked or something like that? I have only installed Chrome extensions from the Chrome Extension Gallry, so I suppose it should be okay?

My blog is www.simon-smith.dk by the way (in danish) - the problen occurs only when the comment form is visible (http://simon-smith.dk/teknik/programmering/backup-af-mysql-database-113#comments)

Hope someone can help me out with this..

Comment: How about other, similar sites? Or does this happen with this site only?

Comment: It must definitely be a problem at your end as the form is not pre-populated in any of the browsers I have tried including Chrome. Don't know how or why it is happening or what to do about it.

Comment: I've just checked a few other blogs, but didn't seem to happen on those..

Comment: A bit unrelated, but Akismet can be rubbish in that it often allows spam through, and blocks legitimate comments. You might want to try a ReCaptcha plugin instead/as well.

Comment: If Simon's PC/browser has indeed been compromised as he is asking then is that not on-topic?

Comment: @James it is, reopened.

Comment: There's a typo in your most recent blog entry title ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a commment on your blog - no problems so far. You might have some malicious extension installed.. Try to remove extension by extension or reinstall chrome.

Comment: Well I haven't installed any plugins recently and I've just deleted the one I had installed later than the last time I checked my blog..

Comment: Try other browsers, or your browser in safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a virus scan of your computer with whatever anti-virus program you have, and maybe a re-installation of your browser... That's pretty much the standard thing to do, but it works most of the time.

And i really like your blog by the way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is malicious javascript coming from an ad (it could even be targeted specifically at Chrome).

Check out [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/273353/was-my-linux-computer-hacked) for some background and more possible answers. The asker had an issue very similar to yours.